# NoMemoryError: failed to allocate memory - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, memory, memory-leaks

I generated a simple script that on other occasions has worked for me, but this is because the amount of information in the loop generates a NoMemoryError error.

I have 16 GB of memory and also a lot of virtual memory available. When I perform the test, the RAM memory is completely filled.

The script is:

```
  require 'rest-client'
  require 'json'
  require 'open-uri'
  require 'csv'

  def self.qos7705egressdiscard_summary
   xml = File.read("#{Rails.root}/public/Discard_qos7705egress.xml")
   data = RestClient.post("http://10.140.255.1:8080/xmlapi/invoke", xml,{:"Content-Type" => 'application/soap+xml'})
   data_parsed = Hash.from_xml(data)
   return data_parsed
  end

  def self.samqos7705egressdiscardtotal_table
   tabletotal = Hash.new
   data_stats = qos7705egressdiscard_summary['Envelope']['Body']['findResponse']['result']['service.SapEgrQosQueueStatsLogRecord']

   data_stats.map do |qosdiscard_device|
    @devicetotal = qosdiscard_device["monitoredObjectSiteName"]
    @servicetotal = qosdiscard_device["monitoredObjectPointer"]
    @porttotal = qosdiscard_device["displayedName"]
    @queueIdtotal = qosdiscard_device["queueId"]
    @discardinproftotal = qosdiscard_device["droppedInProfOctets"].to_i
    @discardoutproftotal = qosdiscard_device["droppedOutProfOctets"].to_i
    time_unixtotal = (qosdiscard_device["timeCaptured"]).to_i/1000
    @timeCapturedtotal = Time.at(time_unixtotal).strftime("%B %e, %Y at %I:%M %p")
    @discardtotal = @discardinproftotal + @discardoutproftotal
    @device_int_stats_total = (@devicetotal+@porttotal+@queueIdtotal).to_s
     hash = Hash[devicetotal: @devicetotal, servicetotal: @servicetotal, porttotal: @porttotal, queueIdtotal: @queueIdtotal, discardtotal: @discardtotal, device_int_stats_total: @device_int_stats_total, timeCapturedtotal: @timeCapturedtotal, time_unixtotal: time_unixtotal]
     tabletotal << hash
     #tabletotal.write(hash)
   end
  end
```

The exact error is:

```
NoMemoryError: failed to allocate memory
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0/irb/inspector.rb:108:in `inspect'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0/irb/inspector.rb:108:in `block in <module:IRB>'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0/irb/inspector.rb:101:in `call'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0/irb/inspector.rb:101:in `inspect_value'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0/irb/context.rb:383:in `inspect_last_value'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0/irb.rb:661:in `output_value'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0/irb.rb:490:in `block (2 levels) in eval_input'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0/irb.rb:623:in `signal_status'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0/irb.rb:486:in `block in eval_input'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:245:in `block (2 levels) in each_top_level_statement'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:231:in `loop'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:231:in `block in each_top_level_statement'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:230:in `catch'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:230:in `each_top_level_statement'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0/irb.rb:485:in `eval_input'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0/irb.rb:395:in `block in start'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0/irb.rb:394:in `catch'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0/irb.rb:394:in `start'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'Maybe IRB bug!
```

On line 25 I added this `tabletotal.write (hash)` to be able to write it on disk and not in memory but I got the following error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `write' for {}:Hash
```

What is the problem here? Also how can I fix it?

Comment: The error is telling you that tabletotal is a Hash, and when you call tabletotal.write, you're calling write on a hash, which throws an error. What are you supposed to call 'write' on?

Comment: Start by making your code less sh*tty. You don't need all those instance variables - just compose a hash straight off and map the input values to the output. Also you should change the signature of the method to take input as an argument so that you can test it in a reasonable manor.

Comment: I found a solution to a problem similar to mine and I wanted to apply it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23520758/failed-to-allocate-memory-no-memoryerror-in-ruby

Comment: I need all those variables because I use them in a html in table format.

Comment: But its not even going to work since each iteration will overwrite the instance variables - you need to iterate through an array or hash in the table. For now just concentrate on input/output.

Comment: I have the same code but with other variables and it does work. The drawback in this is to call an XML variable because it is very heavy.

Comment: You should use Nokogiri to parse the XML document and traverse it instead of turning the whole document into a hash. But refactoring won't hurt here especially since this code will not behave as you intended.

Answer (score 0):

Start by making it less cr*p:

```
def extract_data(input)
  {
    devicetotal: input["monitoredObjectSiteName"],
    servicetotal: input["monitoredObjectPointer"],
    porttotal: input["displayedName"],
    queueIdtotal: input["queueId"],
    discardinproftotal:  input["droppedInProfOctets"].to_i,
    discardoutproftotal: input["droppedOutProfOctets"].to_i,
    time_unixtotal: input["timeCaptured"].to_i/1000
  }.tap do |h|
    h[:timeCapturedtotal] = Time.at(h[:time_unixtotal]).strftime("%B %e, %Y at %I:%M %p"),
    h[:discardtotal] = h[:discardinproftotal] + h[:discardoutproftotal]
    h[:device_int_stats_total] =(h[:devicetotal]+h[:porttotal]+h[:queueIdtotal]).to_s
  end
end
```

This method is really easy to test since you just insert input and write assertions about the output.

If you want to map and apply this to the input array you would do:

```
data_stats.map(&:extract_data)
```

Your code tries to output a hash but uses the shovel operator like on a array. You need to decide if the appropiate output is an array or a hash.

> I need all those variables because I use them in a html in table
>   format.

This won't work - the instance variables will only contain the values from the last element as they get overwritten in each iteration.

You instead need to iterate over an array of hashes or objects in the view:

```
<% @stats.each do |s| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= s[:devicetotal] %></td>
    # ...
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

If you really want to use instance varibles you need to create a object instance for each element:

```
class DataStat
  include ActiveModel::AttributeAssignment
  attr_accessor :devicetotal, :servicetotal # ...

  def self.from_import(input)
    self.new(
      devicetotal: input["monitoredObjectSiteName"],
      servicetotal: input["monitoredObjectPointer"],
      # ...
    )
  end  
end

@stats = data_stats.map { |ds| DataStat.from_import(ds) }
```

You also need to deal with the issue that you´re running out of memory since you are just slop converting the whole XML document into a Ruby hash. You need  to [parse it with Nokogiri](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/parsing_an_html_xml_document.html) instead and extract what you actually need.

Comment: Hello, I have this error `SyntaxError: (irb):29: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting '}'
    servicetotal: input["monitoredObjectPointer"]`

Comment: Hello, I have this error: `=> :extract_data
irb(main):037:0> data_stats.map(&:extract_data)
NoMethodError: private method `extract_data' called for #<Hash:0x007f2510c03b40>
        from (irb):37:in `map'
        from (irb):37`

Comment: Where and how use i this comand ‘data_stats.map(&:extract_data)‘